# Numeric Format for only Positive Integers

Tags: c#, string-formatting, numeric

I'm currently using N0 to format my numbers. Is there a format to use to allow only positive - anything less than 0 should default to 0?

Comment: That seems less formatting and more "business logic" to me, personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by specifying different formats within one format string like this:

```
someNumeric.ToString("N0;\"0\"");
```

or the same as part of Format string:

```
String.Format("{0:0;\"0\";}", someNumeric);
```

The order is (for 2 format string):

```
positiveformat-or-zeroformat;negative
```

See here for further info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator

Comment: Only it should be `"{0:0;\"0\"}"`

Comment: +1. @ntziolis, your format comment for zero was on wrong side. Thanks for sharing interesting formatting tidbit!

Comment: @Alexei thx, you know when it's time to go to bed when you get the format strings wrong xD

Comment: @ntziolis Thank you - although I'm using an UltraGrid, and it doesn't seem to work well with it, this was what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is to change the number value prior to formatting.  For example

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N0}", number < 0 ? 0 : number);
```

Comment: Or just `Math.Max(0, number)`.

Comment: @JaredPar - I actually ended up using your method, since the format didn't work work well with my UltraGrid - thank you! (wish we can mark multiple answers :))